# css disproportionate image scaling

Tags: html, css, image

I apologize for the noob question in advance.

What I would like to do is disproportionate scaling of an image. So if I have an image of 800x600px, I want it to be displayed as 100x100px. Before it worked to just set width and height on the img tag, however, now one of the properties is ignored and my blog entry looks lame.

Help?

Comment: You have this css rule : `.entry IMG:not(.emoji), .s2-entrytext IMG:not(.emoji) {
    height: auto !important;`. Without it you can see your blog will looks like as the following [link](http://i.imgur.com/NLQXswj.png). That `height : auto` has the !important which force height to be relative to width proportion instead of your height setted in your img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `background-size` set to `cover`, this should perserve the scale, cover the whole area and crop areas that overflow:

```
background-image: url('image.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```